# Dispose method is called in case of ReturnRedirectToAction in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC but I have a problem of dispose method is being called. When I am going to login, all the validation and login is working properly but when I am redirecting after a successful login, then in the case of return redirect to action, dispose method is being called.
What should I do?
Here is my controller:

```
 public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    public AdminController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {

    }

    public AdminController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Session["RoleID"] != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleID"]) == Ansits2018.UTILITIES.Constants.Admin)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var accRepo = new AccountRepository();
            int UserID = 0;
            UserID = accRepo.IsUserValid(model.UserName, model.Password);

            if (UserID > 0)
            {
                var user = accRepo.GetUserByUsername(model.UserName);
                Session["CompanyID"] = 1;
                Session["UserID"] = UserID;
                Session["Username"] = model.UserName;
                Session["RoleID"] = user.RoleID;
                Session["Name"] = user.Name;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                                   1,                                   // ticket version
                                                   user.Username,  // authenticated username
                                                   DateTime.Now,                        // issueDate
                                                   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),        // expiryDate
                                                   true,                                // true to persist across browser sessions
                                                   user.RoleID.ToString(),       // can be used to store additional user data
                                                   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath  // the path for the cookie
                                                   );

                // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
                string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                // Add the cookie to the request to save it
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                if (user.RoleID == Ansits2018.UTILITIES.Constants.Admin)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Invalid username or password.";
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && UserManager != null)
        {
            UserManager.Dispose();
            UserManager = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: That is what should happen. What is the problem?

Comment: actually now i've got what is the exact problem . actually i have  a index method but when it comes on ReturnRedirectToAction("Index","Home") it does not go to the index method. That is the real Problem.

Comment: The code in your question is redirecting to the `Index()` method of `AdminController`, not `HomeController`

Comment: yes I am extreamly sorry . it is for admin controller. Have you any idea about? actually when i renameing the Index it gets called but in case of Index it does not get called

Answer (score 0):

RedirectToAction (at least the form you're using) is constructed like this:

```
RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName)
```

So `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` takes you to the Index action in the Home Controller, and `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");` takes you to the Index Action of the Admin Controller.

So if I'm reading your question correctly, you need to change the code to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

Update (in light of comments):

If you are wanting to `RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");` then you'll need to debug your code to find out where the problem is. You can set breakpoints for the debug, or add these debug lines to your code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (Session["RoleID"] != null)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleID"]) == Ansits2018.UTILITIES.Constants.Admin)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var accRepo = new AccountRepository();
        int UserID = 0;
        UserID = accRepo.IsUserValid(model.UserName, model.Password);

        if (UserID > 0)
        {
            var user = accRepo.GetUserByUsername(model.UserName);
            Session["CompanyID"] = 1;
            Session["UserID"] = UserID;
            Session["Username"] = model.UserName;
            Session["RoleID"] = user.RoleID;
            Session["Name"] = user.Name;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                                1,                                   // ticket version
                                                user.Username,  // authenticated username
                                                DateTime.Now,                        // issueDate
                                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),        // expiryDate
                                                true,                                // true to persist across browser sessions
                                                user.RoleID.ToString(),       // can be used to store additional user data
                                                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath  // the path for the cookie
                                                );

            // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            // Add the cookie to the request to save it
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1 #####> RedirectToLocal (valid Login): " + returnUrl);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (user.RoleID == Ansits2018.UTILITIES.Constants.Admin)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2 #####> Invalid Login Attempt - UserID > 0: " + model.UserName + " => " + model.Password));
            TempData["Message"] = "Invalid username or password.";
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3 #####> ModelState Invalid: " + model.UserName + " => " + model.Password);
    return View(model);
}
```

then click the cursor on the Login View Action (not the `[HttpPost]`), hit Debug in the menu and then Start Debugging. Wait for it to all settle down and then login and watch the Debug messages to see which one appears. That should give a good clue as to what's going wrong, and what you need to do.

Comment: No i have to move to the Index action of Admin. But its its not getting me to the index of admin

Comment: @shami sheikh updated the answer to hopefully give you some pointers as to where things are going wrong.